# Why the lib module can't include the 3rd lib in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I had an issue 
"**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils**;" 
when i tried to run an android app that deponds on my own android lib.
Fllowing is my steps:
Created an android project ,and then built a new module named "**sptvlib**" in it.
This module depends on a 3rd party lib named "common-lang" that is a String utils lib.please see the "**sptvlib**" gradle file:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.lang:2.6'
   ...
}
```

After built the whole project, i got the module **sptvlib.aar** file, and copied it to the "libs" directory of another android app project.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
...
    compile(name: 'sptvlib', ext: 'aar')
...
}
```

I built this app successfully, but when it run, the logcat showed " **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**" error.
I have to re-add "commons.lang" declatration to the app project gradle, and then it run ok...  we have added the 3rd party lib to my module use the "compiled". Why the app that deponds on my own module still could't find it in the runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using some function of commons.lang in your main app project.

Since you are using compiled assembled code of your sptvlib library, you can used the compiled exposed functions of sptvlib in your main app project.

But you can not access the library functions of commons.lang directly in your main app project.
This is because you have not added sptvlib code as a module to your app project. you are only using the compiled version of sptvlib.

Comment: so... that i built the "sptvlib.aar" is not a real  lib like as "rxjava", and "retrofit" etc...  if some other apps use the functions of the "sptvlib" that deponds on the "commons.lang" lib  and run ok, we need create a new module in each app project and copy "sptvlib" codes in it, or i got it wrong? Could you have some samples to help me？ How to create a "real" lib?thanks ^_^

Comment: if some other apps use the functions of the "sptvlib" that depends on the "commons.lang" lib should work perfectly. But you can not use the functions of "commons.lang" directly in the app.

Comment: my app don't use the functions of 3rd lib directly, only call some methods of the sptvlib that depends on 3rd lib...